# Deploy a simple Python bot

Tags: python, deployment, telegram

**Code:**

```
    import requests as rq
    from bs4 import BeautifulSoup as bs

    url = "https://apod.nasa.gov/apod/astropix.html"
    page = rq.get(url).content
    soup = bs(page, 'html.parser')
    response = soup.find('img')
    if response == None:
        imglink = soup.find('iframe')['src']
    else:
        imglink = 'https://apod.nasa.gov/apod/' + response['src']
    def main():
        sess = rq.Session()
        cid='**************'
        turl = 'https://api.telegram.org/bot*******************/'
        if response == None:
            imglink = soup.find('iframe')['src']
            params = {'chat_id':cid,'text':imglink}
            sess.post(turl + 'sendMessage', data=params)
        else:
            imglink = 'https://apod.nasa.gov/apod/' + response['src']
            title = soup.find('b').get_text()
            params = {'chat_id':cid,'photo':imglink,'caption':title}
           sess.post(turl + 'sendPhoto', data=params)

    if __name__ == '__main__':
        main()
```

This is a simple bot for sending Nasa picture to my telegram channel. I will be modifying this script to make it happen everyday. But he Question is where do I host them, So that it will run all the time (free) . What is the correct way of doing it.

Comment: There is a free tier of Heroku: https://www.heroku.com/ See if that meets your needs.

Comment: Can I know the exact way of doing It

Comment: I added an answer with the steps to do so. I have a script running on Heroku free tier, and it works well.

Answer (score 0):

I don't know of any providers that would host this for free. For cheap, AWS and Google Cloud all have simple solutions.

Ex: https://cloud.google.com/blog/products/application-development/how-to-schedule-a-recurring-python-script-on-gcp